# use file_exists() to check wordpress uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, file-exists

I have created a directory in Wordpress uploads folder for end user to bulk upload photos via ftp. Images are numbered 1.jpg, 2.jpg... etc. I've generated the image urls successfully, but now I want to test for empty urls - i.e. if "8.jpg" doesn't exist, show a placeholder image from the theme's images folder instead.

I'm trying to use file_exists(), but this returns false every time and always displays the placeholder image. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // create url to image in wordpress 'uploads/catalogue_images/$sale' folder
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();                          
    $sub_dir = $wp_query->queried_object;
    $image = get_field('file_number');
    $image_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . "/catalogue_images/" . $sub_dir->name . "/" . $image . ".JPG"; ?>

    <?php if(file_exists($image_url)){
        echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="" />';
    } else {
        //placeholder
        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_url") . '/images/photo_unavailable.jpg" alt="" />';
    } ?>                                
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: `file_exists` expects an internal file path, not an HTTP path.

Comment: `file_exists` requires the path to the image on the server, not the URL which is relative to the document root. How does the variable content of `$image_url` look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP `file_exists` function mainly [expects an internal server path to the file to be tested](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#refsect1-function.file-exists-parameters). This is made obvious with the [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#refsect1-function.file-exists-examples).

Fortunately, we see that [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) gives us several useful values:

> - 'path' - base directory and sub directory or full path to upload directory.
> - 'url' - base url and sub directory or absolute URL to upload directory.
> - 'subdir' - sub directory if uploads use year/month folders option is on.
> - 'basedir' - **path without subdir.**
> - 'baseurl' - **URL path without subdir.**
> - 'error' - set to false.

I've bolded what we want to use. Using these two values, you have to generate two variables, one for the external URL and one for the internal file path:

```
$image_relative_path = "/catalogue_images/" . $sub_dir->name . "/" . $image . ".JPG";
$image_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . $image_relative_path;
$image_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . $image_relative_path;
```

Then use `file_exists($image_path)` instead of `file_exists($image_url)`.

#### Note

As with the PHP notes on PHP >= 5.0.0, you [can indeed use `file_exists` with some URLs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#refsect1-function.file-exists-notes), however the `http://` protocol is [not supported for the `stat()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php#refsect1-wrappers.http-options) (which is what `file_exists` uses.)

Comment: Working - thank you very much for explaining it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an internal path for checking if a file exists.
So use `$upload_dir['path']` instead `$upload_dir['baseurl']`

> [path] - base directory and sub directory or full path to upload
>   directory.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir